# Find the multiple of n numbers within given range

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math

How can I find the number of multiple for N numbers(as an array input) for a range 1 to K, where 1 < K < 10⁸ and 3 ≤ N < 25.

```
function findNumberOfMultiples(inputArray, maxSize) {   
    var count = 0;
    var tempArray = [];
    for (var i=0; i<maxSize; i++){
        tempArray[i] = 0;
    }

    for (var j=0; j<inputArray.length; j++) {
        for (var i=1; i<=maxSize; i++) {
            if (i % inputArray[j]) {
                tempArray[i-1] = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    for (var i=0; i<maxSize; i++) {
        if (tempArray[i]==1) {
            count++;
        }
    }
 return count;
}
```

The above program fails for large number K. For example, if `inputArray = [2,3,4]`  and `maxSize(k)` is `5`,

- Multiple of 2 is 2,4
- Multiple of 3 is 3
- multiple of 4 is 4

so total number of mutiple of 2 or 3 or 4 is 3  in range 1 to 5

Comment: Describe what you want to do more precisely

Comment: What do you mean it fails?  Do you get an error message?  If so what is it?  Are you getting unexpected values?  If so what are your expected output for a particular input, vs the actual output?

Comment: Three `for` are unnecessary

Comment: @JNYRanger Maybe, memory limit exceeded

Comment: Give examples of what you want to do

Comment: I want the algorithm that has best time complexity.And satiesfies my conditions.

Comment: E.g. he has a range from 1-10. Now he wants to find out how many times he can multiply his numbers in the array while the result is still in the given range right? I'm not sure about how useful this is but that's another story..

Comment: @greenhoorn by the way you have to "she"  :P

Comment: @Ankita The numbers in your array, are they consecutive? or is there any range or any property?

Comment: This link shows a similar query: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/482284/count-of-distinct-multiples-of-n-numbers

Comment: @karthik no number in array is not concecutive.

Comment: @Ankita Yeah, I understood that. Check my answer and test it against your test cases. It works for any K.

Comment: @ShubhamBhattar ya I have seen this link .But unable to implement it.That is code it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this in O(N^2) where N is the number of elements in your array.

let us say you have two element in your array [a1,a2] and the range is K

your answer will be = >

```
  K/a1 + K/a2 - K/lcm(a1,a2) // because you added them in both a1 and a2
```

So If you have `a1,.....ax` elements, your answer would be

```
K/a1+.....K/ax - K/lcm(ai,aj) (you have to replace i,j by (n*n-1)/2 combinations.
```

You  will have to do `K/lcm(ai,aj)` O(N^2) times ((n*n-1)/2 time to be precise). So the algorithm complexity will be O(N^2) (There will be a  Log(min(ai,aj)) factor but that would not make much difference to the overall complexity).
This will work any `K` as it only depends on your innput array size.

```
 public int combinations(int K, int[] input){
    int total = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<input.length;i++){
        total  =  total + Math.floor(K/input[i]);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<input.length;i++){
        for(int j=i+1;j<input.length;j++){
            if(i!=j){
                int lcm =lcmFind(input[i], input[j]);
                total = total - Math.floor(K/lcm);
            }
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```

The test case you have provided:

[image]

Comment: I tried your algorithm with this input combinations(10,[2,3,5,4]) I am getting  -1.499 as answer which is wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by -1.499??? it's integer division. How are you getting  a float ?

Comment: I converted your code to javascript.Try it  on your own.

Comment: there was a small flaw in the answer, I have corrected it. In javascript 3/2 produces 1.5, but in java in produces 1. So where ever I did K/X you just have to convert it to Int by using Math.Floor(K/X).

Comment: @Ankita i have edited the solution, check it now. In the initial code change `for(int j=0;j<input.length;j++)` to `for(int j=i+1;j<input.length;j++)` and add `Math.floor` for divisions.

Comment: Thanks very much.your algorithm was easy and solve my problem.

Comment: No issues. Tested and is perfect

Answer (score 1):

This function seems to do the trick :

```
var findMultiplesLength = function(arrayInput, max) {
  var globalMultiples = [];
  for (var j = 0; j < arrayInput.length; j++) {
    var x = arrayInput[j];
    var n = max / x;
    for (var i=1; i < n; i++) {
      mult = i * x;
      if (globalMultiples.indexOf(mult) === -1) {
        globalMultiples.push(mult);
      }
    }
  }
  return globalMultiples.length;
};
```

EDIT : You won't have any stack error but choosing big values for the range may hang your browser.

Comment: So it don't return answers.That is only the issue.Unable to solve the problem for large range.